# Passing PHP array into a Javascript array without AJAX or JQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

### I have a bunch of parallel arrays in php

```
$phoneNums = array();
$minutesUsed = array();
$plans = array();
$charges = array();
```

---

and I'm trying to put them in arrays in JS so I can access them and print values into the page

```
var phoneNums = <?php echo $phoneNums ?>;
var minutesUsed = <?php echo $minutesUsed ?>;
var plans = <?php echo $plans ?>;
var charge = <?php echo $charges ?>;
```

What ends up happening is my values end up as undefined. How would I pass an array from php to js  this without using AJAX or JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echoing a PHP array will not print its contents. Even if it would, it would not be in the same format that Javascript expects (`[1,2,3]`) - also, associative arrays in PHP work quite differently than JS, where they are objects (`{'x':1,'y':2}`).

[JSON](http://json.org/) is Javascript Object Notation. If you encode your data in JSON (in PHP, you can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to do that), it will be absolutely acceptable for Javascript, so you can simply print it:

```
var phoneNums = <?php echo json_encode($phoneNums); ?>;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lHqmCr)

Comment: Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input.

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion My mistake, check now.

Comment: hmm this time nothing prints out unlike before where it was just undefined.
and it comes up as an empty array in the error console

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion I have added a Demo that shows it working. Are you sure you have an array with that name in that variable scope?

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion In that case it should be an empty array :). `$phoneNums = array();` seems to be quite empty.

Comment: I left out the parts where i populated the array. I figured out the issue was my JS ran before the function call to populate the arrays. My mistake